# If ajax done replace html with the requested data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My problem is, that I want to replace the content in the `tooltip-content`, but it doesn't replace it. 
For example if I replace the `body` content with the `data` it works but it wont replace the `tooltip-content`.

At the moment is a loading sybmol in the `tooltip-content`. It's just HTML and CSS.

I have this javascript:

```
$('td').hover(function () {
    if ($(this).find('div.tooltip').length != 0 ) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "dig.php",
            data: {
                host: $(this).find(' div.tooltip').attr('data-href'),
                server: $(this).find(' div.tooltip').attr('data-server')
            }
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log('worked');
            $(this).find('div.tooltip-content').html(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside ajax success is refers to xhr object. Either you need to pass it as context or set it at as a variable.

```
$('td').hover(function() {
  var $this=$(this);
  if ($this.find('div.tooltip').length != 0) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "dig.php",
        data: {
          host: $(this).find(' div.tooltip').attr('data-href'),
          server: $(this).find(' div.tooltip').attr('data-server')
        }
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        console.log('worked');
        $this.find('div.tooltip-content').html(data);
      });
  }
});
```

You can use `this` inside ajax success if you set context

```
$('td').hover(function() {
  if ($(this).find('div.tooltip').length != 0) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "dig.php",
        context: this,
        data: {
          host: $(this).find(' div.tooltip').attr('data-href'),
          server: $(this).find(' div.tooltip').attr('data-server')
        }
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        console.log('worked');
        $(this).find('div.tooltip-content').html(data);
      });
  }
});
```

REF : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You should explain the OP's mistake in assuming `this` the same throughout

Comment: Why continue to evaluate `$(this)` repeatedly if its result is already stored in a variable?